# Multiuser SMB Mount on Red Hat: Users Seeing Each Other's Folders Despite Separate cifscreds

Tags: redhat, samba, pam, cifs

We are attempting to mount a Windows file system on a Red Hat 9 machine. This Windows file system contains hundreds of accounts with finely tuned access rights.

We are trying to implement the instructions provided in the Red Hat documentation [link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/managing_file_systems/performing-a-multi-user-smb-mount_managing-file-systems).

We have defined a service account with minimal visibility and used it as a 'service account' for mounting, as follows:

```bash
mount -t cifs -o username=minimaluser,cifsacl,multiuser,sec=ntmlssp //machine.name.local/Data /mnt
```

or:

```bash
mount -t cifs -o username=minimaluser,cifsacl,multiuser,sec=ntmlsspi //machine.name.local/Data /mnt
```

Once this is done, the root account on the machine sees nothing more than `minimaluser` in `/mnt/`.

We have two test users, Mickey and Donald, each with different access rights. We connect as Mickey to perform the `cifscreds`:

```bash
cifscreds add -u mickey machine.name.local
```

This works perfectly for Mickey, who can see, with the correct permissions, what is in `/mnt`. However, if Donald logs in, he also sees Mickey's folders and files! (And root does too, along with any other user who connects to the machine via SSH.)

If Donald, in turn, runs:

```bash
cifscreds add -u donald machine.name.local
```

It doesn't change much, and Mickey's folders are still mounted.

This is problematic, and we would like each user to see only their folders when running `cifscreds add...` (which we aim to automate eventually with `pam_cifscreds`).

Do you have any suggestions for us?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT :

We have made progress in our efforts to implement a multiuser SMB mount on Red Hat using Kerberos authentication. Here are the steps we've taken:

1. As root, we run `kinit` for the `minimaluser`:

   ```bash
   kinit minimaluser@name.LOCAL
   ```
2. We then mount the SMB share with the following command:

   ```bash
   mount -t cifs -o username=machine.name.local,multiuser,sec=krb5,cifsacl //machine.name.local/Data /mnt
   ```

   After this step, any user who logs into the machine and runs `kinit` can see the correct contents of `/mnt`. This is great news for us, but we'd like to fully understand the intricacies behind this process.

We are seeking assistance to demystify this and gain a deeper understanding. Additionally, as we plan to automate this process, we want to make sure we have a solid understanding before proceeding.

Any insights into how Kerberos authentication is influencing the multiuser SMB mount in this scenario would be greatly appreciated.